# How can I monitor my database on my webpage before clicking submit button?

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, ajax

I am creating a school database as school homework. I have a little issue with ajax (i think using append). I would like to monitor my sql database as soon as i open my webpage without click submit button. Basically i would like to see data which I saved in my database before I add some new data on webpage. Is there anyway to do it? I would like to share my codes down below, hopefully it will helps.
Thanks Everyone

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


      $('.ajax-form').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var postData = $(this).serialize();
            var url = $(this).attr('action');

            $.ajax({

                url: url,
                data: postData,
                type: $(this).val('method'),
                success: function(data) {
                  if (data.title) {
                    var html = '<ul>';
                    html += '<li>' + data.title + '</li></ul>';

                    $('#result').append(html);

                  }


                  if (!data.error) {

                    $('#result').html(data);

                  }
                });
            });

          --PHP-- -

          $action = $_POST['action'];


          if ($action == 'create') {
            createCourse($_POST['title']);
            getCourseListAsView();
          }
          if ($action == 'getList') {
            getCourseListAsView();
          }


          /*
           * Function Create Course
           * This will create a new Course object and persist it to the database.
           *  */

          function createCourse($title) {
            /* Create new Course Entity */
            $course = new Course;
            /* Fill course with data */
            $course - > setTitle($title);

            /* Persost Object to Database */
            $dbConfigObject = new DbConfig;
            $dbConnection = $dbConfigObject - > getDBConnection();

            $query = "INSERT INTO courses(title) VALUES('$title')";
            $query_lecture_name = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query);

            if (!$query_lecture_name) {
              die('QUERY FAILED');
            }
          }

          function getCourseListAsView() {

            $dbConfigObject = new DbConfig;
            $dbConnection = $dbConfigObject - > getDBConnection();

            $query = "SELECT * FROM courses";
            $search_query = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query);

            $listview = "<ul class='list-unstyled'>";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_query)) {
              //title column in db
              $listview. = "<li>".$row['title'].
              "</li>";
            }
            $listview. = "</ul>";

            echo $listview;
          }

          die();
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <form method="post" id="add-lecture-form" class="col-xs-6 ajax-form" action="Controller/CourseController.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="create">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="add a lecture">
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="col-xs-6">


    <div id="lecture-result">
    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Looks like you’re already on the right track with `$action==‘getList’`. So I presume you already have an idea how to do it. What part are you not getting?

Comment: What is missing from your question is actual vs. desired. "I want x, but I'm getting y." Or, "when I ask for x, I get error z."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach I'd take. I'm only using the Form element for styling and maybe you'll want to use the jquery validation.   When the page first loads it'll fire the `getList()` method which makes a post to your backend without a title but with the action property set to `getList` which causes your backend to create an html string of your data and returns this.  Put the returned data object as the html of the `lecture-result` div.

Then for your form submit I intercept the click event and send the title entered in the form and the action property of `create`.  This causes your backend to insert the title.  Once that comes back as a success I call `getList`.   If you wanted to save a call you could return `getCourseListAsView` when you call the `create` action.

```
<div class="row">

  <form method="post" id="add-lecture-form" class="col-xs-6 ajax-form">
    <input type="hidden" id="url" value="Controller/CourseController.php" />
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="create">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="add a lecture">
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div id="lecture-result"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  getList();

  $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {

    var url = $("#url").val();
    var postData = {};

    postData.action = 'getList';
    postData.title = $("#title").val();

    $.ajax({

      url: url,
      data: postData,
      type: 'post',
      success: function() {
        getList();
      }
    });
  });



});

var getList = function() {
      var url = $("#url").val();
      var postData = {};

      postData.action = 'getList'

      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: postData,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
          $('#result').html(data);
        }
      });
    }
```

;